# How can I specify complex Maven configuration options on the command line?

Tags: maven, maven-3, command-line-interface, wildfly, wildfly-8

For example, I want to use the Wildfly deploy plugin, as outlined here:

http://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-artifact-mojo.html

To deploy, I would use a command like `mvn wildfly:deploy -Dfilename=my.ear`.  But let's say I want to deploy to a particular server group.  Using a POM, I would add:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
 <configuration>
   <domain>
     <server-groups>
       <server-group>main-server-group</server-group>
     </server-groups>
   </domain>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But if I can't change the POM, how would I pass this configuration in on the CLI or in `$HOME\.m2\settings.xml`?

The usage page indicates a configuration "type" of `org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.domain.Domain` for a "domain" option but I don't know how to type those options out on the CLI.  Obvious answers like `-Ddomain.server-groups.server-group=my-server-group` don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you could change the pom using a property like `<server-group>${server.group}</server-group>` should work. I don't think maven has support for complex attribute properties like that.

If that's not possible you could file a [feature request](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP).

Comment: Thanks.  The question was, given that I can't change the POM, is this possible on the CLI or through local settings.xml.  It would surprise me if it wasn't possible on the CLI somehow.

Comment: The issue is the parameter for the configuration is a Domain object. I don't think maven supports properties to complex configuration parameters. I think something would have to be introduced to allow maybe a comma delimited property value that can be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to the overall question, but to your specific problem.

Changing the version in the pom to [1.2.2.Final](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html), you can now do:

```
-Dwildfly.serverGroups=main-server-group
```

which I guess wasn’t available in 1.1.0.